# Reinstall or repair Network-manager-gnome in Ubuntu lucid lynx 10.04.3 LTS offline

Tags: networkmanager

My custom made lubuntu slim 10.04 LTS based distro with many official repositories from ubuntu based distros and stable distros/softwares ppas has a problem with network-manager, is there a way to repair it ?

I tried to download network-manager from ubuntu packages website, is there a way to install them by synaptic ???

Is there a way to reinstall lubuntu without losing anyting ???

Comment: You're likely to end up with problems like this when you add repositories that are for another distribution. If you can't find a ppa for a piece of software for your distro, it may be better to install from source or a `.tgz`-style package and take care of its dependencies manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can reconfigure a package using `dpkg-reconfigure package-name`.

You can reinstall in apt-based distributions by doing `apt-get install --reinstall package-name`.

The Synaptic front-end will also let you reinstall by right-clicking the package and selecting "Mark for Reinstallation".

You can install downloaded packages by double-clicking them or by running `dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb`.